# Storing Values of An Array to Chrome Local Storage & Retrieving Them

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am trying to save values entered into a form to the local storage,
When I check the local storage the key i am using is in it along with `[]` as its only value

Does that mean it is entering it as an array? It is just non populating the array?

As I have read I am using `stringify to setItem and parse to getItem`

How do I add values from the array to the key in localstorage and then retrieve them? I have wrote a solution out that generates no errors, but it does not enter anything but `keyWords []`
Also I can no retrieve anyhting with my current program but I try with the

```
loadKeyWords();
```

Here is my code,

```
localArray = [];
localStorage.setItem('keyWords', JSON.stringify(localArray));

function setArrayInLocalStorage(keyWords, localArray) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(localArray));
}

function getArrayInLocalStorage(keyWords) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keyWords));
}

function loadKeyWords() { 
     $('#keyWords').html('');
     localArray = getArrayInLocalStorage('keyWords');
    //for all the items in the array...
    for(var i = 0; i < localArray.length; i++) {
      //add them to the UL
      $('#keyWords').append('<li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">'+localArray[i]+'</li>'); 
        }
    }

$('#add').click( function() {
   var Description = $('#description').val();
  if($("#description").val() === '') {
    $('#alert').html("<strong>Warning!</strong> Enter some words you hate!");
    $('#alert').fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
    return false;
   }
    $('#keyWords').prepend("<li><input id='check' name='check' type='checkbox'/>" + Description + "</li>");
   $('#form')[0].reset();
   localArray.push(Description);
   setArrayInLocalStorage('keyWords', localArray);
   loadKeyWords(); 
   return false;
});

  $('#clear').click( function() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    location.reload();
    return false;
  });

loadKeyWords();
```

Here is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Wuno Zensorship</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="icon48.png">

 <section>
<form id="form" action="#" method="POST">
<input id="description" name="description" type="text" />
<input id="add" type="submit" value="Add" />
<button id="clear">Clear All</button>
</form>
<div id="alert"></div>
<ul id="keyWords"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

for your code:

```
function setArrayInLocalStorage(keyWords, localArray) {
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(localArray));
}
```

It should be:

```
function setArrayInLocalStorage(keyWords, localArray) {
localStorage.setItem(keyWords, JSON.stringify(localArray));
}
```

key is not defined.

I'm also unsure of what your html looks like, since its not given to us. Are you sure that you are passing in a value for Description and that the function is actually called when you add a function? I'd put a console log on the click event on element add to ensure that the function is called and I'd also console log the value of the variable Description.

Its also possible that whatever element has the id "add" is a submit button, which means that it will trigger a refresh event, so you'd have to use 
`$('#add').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();`

Here's the html I testes, and the items do appear in localStorage. Check your developer tools and resource to make sure that it stays in localStorage:

```
  <div id="keywords">
   <form id="form">
    <input id="description" type="text" name="firstname">
    <button id="add">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: I added my html. And the key is being added to the local storage, it is just not adding any of the values I push to the arrat

Comment: Okay ran it on my labtop and the value is getting stored in localstorage. My first correction seems, incorrect labeling of the variable seems to be causing the issue.

Comment: Agree with Michael, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

```
localArray = [];

// 1. For consistency sake, you should call setArrayInLocalStorage to store the array
// 2. Just so that you know, everytime your app starts, you store an empty array into it
localStorage.setItem('keyWords', JSON.stringify(localArray));

function setArrayInLocalStorage(keyWords, localArray) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(localArray));
}

function getArrayInLocalStorage(keyWords) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keyWords));
}

function loadKeyWords() {
    // 3. I suggest you create local variable and store $('#keyWords') in it and use that variable in this function, more efficient that way
    $('#keyWords').html('');
    localArray = getArrayInLocalStorage('keyWords');
    //for all the items in the array...
    for (var i = 0; i < localArray.length; i++) {
        //add them to the UL
        $('#keyWords').append('<li><input id="check" name="check" type="checkbox">' + localArray[i] + '</li>');
    }
}

$('#add').click(function() {
    // 4. Try to stick with convent and define variable using camel case
    var Description = $('#description').val();
    // 5. You already have the string/empty string in Description, you can simply use it here to compare with ''
    if ($("#description").val() === '') {
        $('#alert').html("<strong>Warning!</strong> Enter some words you hate!");
        $('#alert').fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
        return false;
    }
    // 6. Not sure why you take the time to build the list in html, yet to rebuild it in the function call below
    $('#keyWords').prepend("<li><input id='check' name='check' type='checkbox'/>" + Description + "</li>");
    // 7. Because we don't have your html code, not sure what this does and why you'll need it
    $('#form')[0].reset();
    localArray.push(Description);
    setArrayInLocalStorage('keyWords', localArray);
    loadKeyWords();
    return false;
});

$('#clear').click(function() {
    // 8. You might want to consider removing the keyWords instead of clearing your local storage here
    window.localStorage.clear();
    location.reload();
    return false;
});

loadKeyWords();
```

Aside from the eight comments I have, I don't see why your should store the keywords in the local storage and retrieve the.  If you like, please add your html code also and we can assist further.

Comment: This does not work, I am saving values to local storage so the user can browser the web with my extension running doing its jump censoring the values they add.